# Xml Transform from Attributes to Elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this string (which is stored in an XElement):

```
<MergeFields xmlns="urn:www-xxx-com:schema.xx-calls">
  <MergeField name="XAccountID" value="1234" />
  <MergeField name="XDate" value="01/20/2013 10:00:00 AM" />
</MergeFields>
```

Mergefields will be storing different attributes.

I need to convert it to a string like this:

```
<MergeFields>
  <XAccountID>1234</XAccountID>
  <XDate>01/20/2013 10:00:00</XDate>
</MergeFields>
```

I have read about using XSLT, but I'm having a hard time finding sample code. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are some good XSLT tutorials on IBM's [DeveloperWorks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/) website. I'd recommend reading those; they should include examples.

Generally, the right answer is to start with the Identity Transform. Then add a template 
which handles the exceptional cases.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Identity: Copy all nodes unchanged, recursively -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Exception: Attributes of MergeFields should be turned into elements
       with the same name and value -->
  <xsl:template match="MergeFields/@*">
    <xsl:element name="name()"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>    
  </template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```